# React nested route on root issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

When I try to have nested routes on my root route I run into a problem.
I have 3 "main" routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
</Switch>
```

On my `Home` component I have a nested router like this:

```
<div>
  <Route path="/" render={() => <div>Home</div>} />
  <Route path="/test" render={() => <div>Test Route</div>} />
</div>
```

The Home component has a sidebar HOC which contains the Links.

```
<Sidebar>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
  <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>
</Sidebar>
```

When Im on my Root component and click the `Test` link, the route on the nested router changes to the Test component which is correct. Whenever I go the login and/or logout route it tries to display that in the nested router in the Home component

Any idea what is going wrong?

EDIT: I've tried the example @Tholle provided. Unfortunately it still doesn't work the way I want to. See this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8173knklw2) I made to reproduce my problem.

Comment: It looks like your question was cut short at the end. Can you add the rest?

Comment: Network error, give me a second. 
EDIT: Fixed now @Tholle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your links need to point to `"/home/testX"`  and the nested routes need to handle `"/home/testX"`.  Also you will need a route for `"/home"` in the root. I don't believe the Link component is scoped to the route in which it is called.  Meaning that to link to `"/test1"` assumes that is the base route.  However, the rendering of test1 actually takes place in the home component.

To put it another way:  In order to get to `/home/test1` you must first get the home component (`/home`) to render which can then render the route for test1 (`/home/test1`)

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ql4omjxv1)

Here is an example that provides a bit more flexibility [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kjxjzl656).  This one will require a redirect of "/" because it depends on the path being used and it needs to be "/home" not "/".

Hope this helps.  Hope I got it all right.

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` component makes sure that only the first `Route` that matches is rendered. To stop `<Route path="/" component={Home} />` from always being rendered, you can set the [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool) prop to `true`.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y09vk5rr4))**

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't tackle my problem though. See the edit I made to reproduce my problem.